# Add file submitted to specific folder based on answer in google forms

Tags: google-drive, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to create different subfolders for uploaded files based on the multiple choice question i have in one of my google forms. 
The form is for certain locations, so based on the location that is selected i want it to create/add the uploaded file to that specific subfolder.

Is there a way to do this or use apps scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Google Forms doesn't include this a build-in feature. It's possible that exists an add-on to add this feature, also it's possible to use Google Apps Script to add it.

There are many ways to achieve the desired final result, as using a on form submit trigger, a time driven trigger, a custom menu / dialog or by running the script from the script editor.

To learn about Google Apps Script, please checkout https://www.google.com/script/start

To ask for a software recommendation, pleas post your question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com